# Vue-cli 3.x watch and compile scss-files

Tags: vue.js, sass

I've a folder some scss-files under `src/assets/scss` and I want to accomplish, that my `src/assets/scss/main.scss` is watched and compiled during `npm run serve` and `npm run build`. 
The compiled file should be placed in public or in dist, I don't know what the better solution is. I've tried to add an output-directory to my `vue.config.js` but nothing worked.

This is my current vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: '@import "@/assets/scss/main.scss";',
                outputDir: './public/css/main.css'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The styles from main.scss will not be loaded in a vue-component. These styles will be loaded globally for the whole website.

Comment: i understand that you have multiple scss files into your `src/assets/scss`folder and you want them be compiled ?

Comment: Exactly. Main.scss as starting point. In this file all other files are included.

Comment: So, add `@import "@/assets/scss/otherfile1.scss`, `@import "@/assets/scss/otherfile2.scss`   in the beginning of your `main.scss`